# JOOQ MYSQL QUERY

Tags: jooq

```
select question.*, 
       question_option.id 
from question 
left join question_option on question_option.question_id = question.id;
```

how do i write question.* in jooq instead of specifying all the entity vaiables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `field()` or `asterisk()` methods from the JOOQ generated objects which are extended from `TableImpl`.

For example, if you just want to query the fields of a record:

`dsl.select(QUESTION.fields()).from...`

If you need fields from the join too:

`dsl.select(QUESTION.asterisk(), QUESTION_OPTION.ID).from...`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you generate the metamodel so you can use

```
dsl.select(QUESTION.fields()), QUESTION_OPTION.ID)...
```